# Import HTML files in AWS email templates

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api, email-templates

Is there a way to import HTML files instead of just writing the code in the HTML part in AWS email template api?

```
{
    "Template": {
        "TemplateName": "Paradigm Initiative Monthly Newsletter",
        "SubjectPart": "Greetings, {{name}}!",
        "TextPart": "Dear {{name}},\r\nYour favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}.",
        "HtmlPart": "<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><p>Your favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}.</p>"
        // Instead of writing the HTML code this way, is it possible to import it and then use "index.html"
    }
}
```